# Treat as number and search in between

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table there is a column which its type is varchar. And the value in all rows is like this:

```
 +------------+----+
 |   price    | id |
 +------------+----+
 | Rp 100000  | 1  |
 | Rp 200000  | 2  |
 | Rp 50000   | 3  |
 | Rp 1000    | 4  |
 | Rp 1000    | 5  |
 | Rp 2000    | 6  |
 | Rp 35000   | 7  |
 | Rp 45000   | 8  |
```

I tried this query

```
  SELECT table WHERE price between Rp 100000 AND Rp 200000
```

But the result it it still fetch the row which is not in the between range, such as it selects the id `1,2,4,5,6`.

I think it is caused of `0` value which the query try to ignore.
And i think to solve this is by treating this var-char as number (price/amount in Rupiah) so that the query recognize what I am trying to do.

Can anybody help how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `price` field?

Comment: Bad table design. Have a separate column for Rp!

Comment: It's old design. But there had been thousands rows there. And i need to adapt with that. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select * from yourTable
 where substring(price,3) between 100000 and 200000
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37197/4

You don't need to `cast` the value it will be implicit done.

What the `substring(price,3)` is doing is getting everything from the third character of the column `price` therefore without the `RF` character (note also the blank space) and comparing with the numbers on the `between` operator.

The `substring(price,3)` will return a string but since it is composed only by numbers the mysql on comparing with the numbers will implicit convert it.

Comment: what if I want to sum it first?

Comment: You should update your question or create a new one referencing this one. We here try to be as objective as we can. And I did not understand what you mean sum it first! What is it that you want to sum? is there any rules to apply the sum? See that it should be a different question. Consider in accept this one if it solve your actual problem.

Comment: no it's not a good solution. you dont make it as real integer then because it can't be sumed.

Comment: Please read your question before saing its not a good solution. You did **NOT** ask anything about sum ont it. Either update your question or create a new one. Right now this answer is totally perfect for what you have asked. StackOverflow is not a site where people solve their problems only it is a knowledge base and as so the question and answer should attend to each other.  If you like to sum the values, add this issue to your question then I will update my answer or someone else will add another answer for you.